# C3p0 Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, datasource, c3p0

I have configured the following c3p0 configuration to avoid database connectivity issue & network connectivity issue in my project. I have executed the jar file. For testing purpose, just I have stopped the mysql service and check the log. I have found below mentioned error log also tool hangs during execution. I have used hibernate-core version "3.6.9.Final", hibernate-c3p0 version "3.6.9.Final", spring version "3.1.1.RELEASE", c3p0 version as "0.9.5.1" also MYSQL database. Could you please check and advise how to solve this.

**Configuration:-**

```
ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
dataSource.setJdbcUrl(jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_qa);
dataSource.setUser(test);
dataSource.setPassword(test);
dataSource.setAcquireIncrement(7);
dataSource.setPreferredTestQuery("SELECT 1");
dataSource.setBreakAfterAcquireFailure(false);
dataSource.setAcquireRetryAttempts(10);
dataSource.setAcquireRetryDelay(10000);
dataSource.setLoginTimeout(25200);
dataSource.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(30);
dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(200);
dataSource.setMinPoolSize(1);
dataSource.setTestConnectionOnCheckout(true);
dataSource.setTestConnectionOnCheckin(true);
dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(60);
dataSource.setCheckoutTimeout(60000);
dataSource.setAutomaticTestTable("test_c3p0");
```

**persistence.xml:-**

```
<persistence-unit name="org.jbpm.persistence.jpa.testcon">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/JBPMorm.xml</mapping-file>
        <class>org.jbpm.persistence.processinstance.ProcessInstanceInfo</class>
        <class>org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo</class>
        <class>org.drools.persistence.info.WorkItemInfo</class>
        <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.ProcessInstanceLog</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.BTMTransactionManagerLookup" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

**Error Log:-**

```
Feb 15, 2016 5:33:41 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
Feb 15, 2016 5:33:41 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
Feb 15, 2016 5:33:41 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
Feb 15, 2016 5:33:41 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
Feb 15, 2016 5:35:02 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
Feb 15, 2016 5:35:02 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
Feb 15, 2016 5:35:02 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
Feb 15, 2016 5:35:02 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
Feb 15, 2016 5:35:02 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
Feb 15, 2016 5:35:02 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
Feb 15, 2016 5:35:02 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
Feb 15, 2016 5:35:02 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertJdbcAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:424)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:410)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:683)
    at com.test.usermanagement.dao.BaseDao.create(BaseDao.java:43)
    at com.test.workflow.dao.MessageQErrorLogDaoImpl.create(MessageQErrorLogDaoImpl.java:25)
    at com.test.workflow.dao.MessageQErrorLogDaoImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d1d23e85.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at com.test.workflow.dao.MessageQErrorLogDaoImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$66c2452a.create(<generated>)
    at com.test.workflow.services.MessageQErrorLogServiceImpl.create(MessageQErrorLogServiceImpl.java:33)
    at com.test.messageq.IntegrationConsumer.createMessageQErrorLog(IntegrationConsumer.java:874)
    at com.test.messageq.IntegrationConsumer.createAndInitiateArticle(IntegrationConsumer.java:628)
    at com.test.messageq.IntegrationConsumer.main(IntegrationConsumer.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:340)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:166)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.prepare(IdentityGenerator.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2345)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2852)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:697)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:686)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    ... 47 more
```

Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/25350-problem-with-c3p0 check this, Also it could be firewall issue

Comment: I have stopped the mysql service, so the exception occurred. But I don't know why the tool was hanged.